# how can i get an entry form based on selected drop down details in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Based on drop down list details if we select the user in that list how can I get an entry form to fill that particular selected user details in the form?

Comment: `how can i get an entry form?` meaning

Comment: if i have users like student teacher in the drop down list. when i select student in drop down list we need to get particular form regarding student. similarly for teacher his unique form.

Comment: Create two forms for each case and show them only based on the selected item in the select.

Comment: If you select a student get the Student Name or ID using drpDown.SelectedItem.Value. And based on the value you can get the particular form.

Answer (score 0):

- Get the `SelectedValue` from the user dropdown list that will give you `UserID`
- Use this `UserID` to get user details from the db table
- For the user dropdown list create a `SelectedIndexChanged` event
- Trigger the method that fills the user data in the form, from this event

Hope this helps...